# How else can one present an architecture document besides as a series of views?

Tags: language-agnostic, architecture

Most, if not all architecture documents I've seen (and developed) have been presented as a series of views (Logical, Physical, Use-case etc).  Is this the preferred layout?  What other styles are there?

Answer (score 2):

Since it's complex, it's hard to do otherwise.

I like to start with the one-paragraph summary of the overall requirements.  If there isn't a one-paragraph summary, that's -- perhaps -- the most important thing to build.

Once the summary is out of the way, there's an overview of architectural features.  And after that, no one will read a single word.

It isn't a novel.  There's no story arc.  No drama.  No conflict.  No characters.  At least, I can't find a way to make an architecture readable.

The best you can hope for is a reference work with enough indexes, cross references, overviews and sidebars that people use it.

Indeed, it's the pull-outs that matter.  The picture are all anyone will ever use.  And those will get put into PPT's for presentation internally and externally.

So, don't waste a lot of time on writing.  Invest time in overviews, summaries, feature lists and pictures people want to use every day.

Answer (score 0):

This may be WAY off topic, but is there anyway to use [Joel's ideas on making specifications 'fun'](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000033.html) usable is this realm?

Comment: No it's not off topic, IMO.  However, it isn't helpful, either.  When architecture is a bunch of pictures, you've about hit many of Joel's points.

Comment: The humor in descriptions was the part I was thinking of.  If you can make the text somewhat enjoyable to read it can be much more useful.